# Licensing implications of calling 7-Zip from within proprietary application

Tags: lgpl, 7zip

I want to use 7-Zip within my proprietary application.

7-Zip is LGPL

Consider that within my application I call via its command line interface using `system()` something like this: `system( "7-Zip -blah -blah" );`

1. If I use 7-Zip this way do I have any obligations under the LGPL?
2. If I want to distribute 7-Zips' 7z.dll and 7z.exe with my application so that the user does not need to install 7-Zip separately do I have any obligations under the LGPL?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the user is providing 7zip, no.
2. Yes, you would need to provide the 7zip source if requested as you are distributing binaries.

You can also use the 7zip DLL directly without issue as it is LGPL - once again you would need to offer the 7zip source code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the lzma SDK directly, that code was placed in the public domain (see the headers if you don't believe me) so you are fine to incorporate it into your app without having to worry about the LGPL.